# Playback audio on android @ website

Tags: android, html

I'm looking for a way to play an audio stream on android without using flash.

What I've tried so far:

This just claims "Sorry, this video cannot be played."

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://194.106.119.243/powerhit_hi.ogg" tabindex="0"></video>
```

The following simply doesn't do anything. As far as I googled it looks like Android does not support the audio tag at all till 2.3 and at 2.3 it does support it but non of the codecs work so it doesn't actually work.

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls" preload="none" autoplay="autoplay" tabindex="0">
    <source src="http://194.106.119.243/powerhit_hi.ogg"></source>
    <source src="http://194.106.119.243/powerhit_hi.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Android 2.2 device and [I can get `video` to work](http://www.dotrob.com/demo/video/android-video.html), though you should note a few things:

- it launches a separate window to play video - they don't play inline in the page
- because of the above the controls attribute has no effect
- autoplay is generally ignored on mobile devices so users don't incur data charges unless they've explicitly requested the media
- make sure you have the correct MIME types set up in your server config, [HTML5 Boilerplate can help with that](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

I think your example is failing because `.ogg` is usually an audio file (MIME audio/ogg), the equivalent video container would be `.ogv` (MIME video/ogg), but simply renaming the file is unlikely to work, you'd have to get the audio encoded into a video file, perhaps with some static picture for the video.

Like you, [I couldn't get `audio` to play anything on my device](http://www.dotrob.com/demo/video/android-audio.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to play the mp3 or ogg stream using the video tag :/ I'm not able to modify the stream itself.

Comment: @Peeter I don't think you'll be able to play back something that isn't a video stream with the video tag